# Getting Turtle to Bounce Off the Walls

Tags: python, int, turtle-graphics

I am making a program for somebody, so they can exercise their eyes, and I am using the turtle, so it will move randomly.
I want the turtle to bounce off the walls, so that it does not disappear off the sides, never to be seen again!
I have looked at: [TurtleGraphics Python: Bouncing turtle off the walls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457332/turtlegraphics-python-bouncing-turtle-off-the-walls/1457659#1457659) and used some code from jnylen, so some credit goes to him!
Anyway, here is my old, and terrible code (This is kept for reference):

```
from random import *
from turtle import *
penup() # Get rid of those lines it leaves behind!
def main():
    while True: # I want this to be infinite
        a = randint(1,600)
        print a
        b = randint(1,359)
        print b
        c = randint(1,600)
        print c
        d = randint(1,359)
        print d #Checking my randoms
        forward(a)
        edge() # Keep calling edge, so it will bounce on the edge.
        left(b)
        edge() # Keep calling edge, so it will bounce on the edge.
        forward(c)
        edge() # Keep calling edge, so it will bounce on the edge.
        right(d)
        edge() # Keep calling edge, so it will bounce on the edge.

def edge():
    x, y = position()
    top = window_height()/2
    bottom = -top
    right = window_width()/2
    left = -right
    if (x <= left and 90 <= heading() <= 270) or (right <= x and not 90 <= heading() <= 270):
        f = 178 * h
        left(f)
        main()
    elif (y <= bottom and heading() >= 180) or (top <= y and heading <= 180):
        f = -2 * heading()
        left(f)
        main()
    else:
        main()
main()
```

However, When I run it, I get the output:

```
189
199
553
152
26
175
597
263
119
201
582
329
231
267
344
28

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/George/Desktop/Eyes.py", line 39, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/George/Desktop/Eyes.py", line 15, in main
    edge()
  File "C:/Users/George/Desktop/Eyes.py", line 38, in edge
    main()
  File "C:/Users/George/Desktop/Eyes.py", line 15, in main
    edge()
  File "C:/Users/George/Desktop/Eyes.py", line 38, in edge
    main()
  File "C:/Users/George/Desktop/Eyes.py", line 15, in main
    edge()
  File "C:/Users/George/Desktop/Eyes.py", line 38, in edge
    main()
  File "C:/Users/George/Desktop/Eyes.py", line 15, in main
    edge()
  File "C:/Users/George/Desktop/Eyes.py", line 31, in edge
    left(f)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Please, can somebody help me fix this. I have tried setting `f` to a `float`, a `string` and an `int`, but nothing works! This is probably something really obvious, so if it is, sorry.

Here is my new, and hopefully, correct code:

```
from random import *
from turtle import *
penup() # Get rid of those lines it leaves behind!
def main():
    while True: # I want this to be infinite
        a = randint(1,600)
        print a
        b = randint(1,359)
        print b
        c = randint(1,600)
        print c
        d = randint(1,359)
        print d #Checking my randoms
        forward(a)

        x, y = position()
        top = window_height()/2
        bottom = -top
        right = window_width()/2
        l = -right

        if (x <= l and 90 <= heading() <= 270) or (right <= x and not 90 <= heading() <= 270):
            f = 178 * heading()
            left(f)
            print "1"
        elif (y <= bottom and heading() >= 180) or (top <= y and heading <= 180):
            f = -2 * heading()
            left(f)
            print "2"
        else:
            print "3"

        left(b)

        x, y = position()
        top = window_height()/2
        bottom = -top
        right = window_width()/2
        l = -right
        if (x <= l and 90 <= heading() <= 270) or (right <= x and not 90 <= heading() <= 270):
            f = 178 * heading()
            left(f)
            print "1"
        elif (y <= bottom and heading() >= 180) or (top <= y and heading <= 180):
            f = -2 * heading()
            left(f)
            print "2"
        else:
            print "3"

        forward(c)

        x, y = position()
        top = window_height()/2
        bottom = -top
        right = window_width()/2
        l = -right
        if (x <= l and 90 <= heading() <= 270) or (right <= x and not 90 <= heading() <= 270):
            f = 178 * heading()
            left(f)
            print "1"
        elif (y <= bottom and heading() >= 180) or (top <= y and heading <= 180):
            f = -2 * heading()
            left(f)
            print "2"
        else:
            print "3"


        right(d)

        x, y = position()
        top = window_height()/2
        bottom = -top
        right = window_width()/2
        l = -right
        if (x <= l and 90 <= heading() <= 270) or (right <= x and not 90 <= heading() <= 270):
            f = 178 * heading()
            left(f)
            print "1"
        elif (y <= bottom and heading() >= 180) or (top <= y and heading <= 180):
            f = -2 * heading()
            left(f)
            print "2"
        else:
            print "3"


main()
```

Comment: Beside @lejlot's answer, your program is bound to crash eventually, as it contains an infinite recursion in it (you call `main` which calls `edge` which calls `main` again etc.).

Comment: I know, I am going to refine the code, so it does not call so many functions when I actually finish the project

Comment: If you don't use `from <module> import *` the cause of your problems would probably have been more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You overwritten the `left` command to the int value here:

```
left = -right
```

so when you try to turn your turtle with

```
left(f)
```

you try to call the `int` object, simply rename your local variable `left`

Comment: Thanks for answer, the program now runs, but the turtle does not bounce, it just carries on forever!

Comment: BartoszKP pointed out the important logical error which has to be solved in order to make this work - your multi-level recursion is not just about efficiency, it is simply incorrect code. My answer only addresses the syntatical issue, not the conceptual error

Comment: Oh! I have just realised how stupid I have been! This code will never work, as it only does `forward(a)` and then calls `edge()` which calls `main` which runs `forward(a)` and then calls `edge()` again! What was I thinking?!

Comment: Exactly, after fixing this and the error outlined in my answer, everything should go back to normal (after also removing those recurrences, which truly are **incorrect**, not just inefficient)

Comment: I have refined my code now. I have edited it in the question.